# How asp.net creates session ids?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, sessionid

How asp.net creates session ids? are there any algorithm or math calculation or something like that?
(I'm trying to make a bot program for a website but I need create sessionid without getting it from server response)

Comment: I hope it is **not** possible.

Comment: The server should create session ids, not clients.

Comment: You can customize how the server creates session ids by implementing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager(v=vs.110).aspx.  You need a really good reason to do this, though.

Comment: Unless you have a *very* good reason to change how session ids are generated, **don't**.  If you are new to C#, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you don't have a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can't be done, to generate session id without server. Server should track those sessions and generate specific ids by its configuration. So probably it needs to be requested from the server.

Comment: Session ids *absolutely* **must** be generated on the server.

Comment: It's perfectly doable without a server, in fact, the client can pick **any string** and use it as a session id. But, with the probability close to 1, this will **not match with any existing sessions** and thus, a new, empty session will be created at the server.